# git svn clone fails on Mac OS X: "Temp file with moniker 'svn_delta' already in use"

Tags: macos, perl, git, svn, macports

I've installed git-core (+svn) on my Mac from MacPorts.  This has given me:

```
git-core @1.7.12.2_0+credential_osxkeychain+doc+pcre+python27+svn
subversion @1.7.6_2
```

I'm attempting to call something like the following:

```
git svn clone http://my.svn.com/svn/area/subarea/project -s
```

The output looks something like this:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/bitwise/work/svn/project/.git/
Using higher level of URL: http://my.svn.com/svn/area/subarea/project => http://my.svn.com/svn/area
A   folder/file.txt
    A       folder/file2.txt
   [... some number of files from svn ... ]
    A       folder44/file0.txt
Temp file with moniker 'svn_delta' already in use at /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.4/Git.pm line 1024.
```

I've done the usual searches but most of the threads seem to trail off without proposing a clear fix.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add this setting to your `~/.subversion/servers` file:

```
[global]
http-bulk-updates=on
```

I had this issue on Linux, and saw the above workaround on [this thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-users/201307.mbox/%3C51D79BDD.5020106@wandisco.com%3E).  I **think** I ran into this because I forced [Alien SVN](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Alien-SVN-v1.7.3.1/src/subversion/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/Core.pm) to build with subversion 1.8 which uses the serf library now instead of neon for https, and apparently git-svn doesn't play nicely with serf.

Comment: This worked for me when I upgrade to Subversion 1.8 on Ubuntu Precise via https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/+archive/subversion-1.8/+packages

Comment: This worked for me and I'm on windows.  See my windows solution here (this is somewhat recursive): http://stackoverflow.com/a/20889647/61624

Answer (score 2):

Note that [git 1.8.5rc3 (release November 20st, 2013](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5fd09df3937f54c5cfda4f1087f5d99433cce527/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.5.txt#L56-L61), [announced here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/238099)) now includes:

- "`git-svn`" has been taught to use the [**`serf`** library](https://code.google.com/p/serf/), which is the [only option SVN 1.8.0 offers us when talking the HTTP protocol](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#neon-deleted) (no more [neon](http://webdav.org/neon/)).
- "`git-svn`" talking over an `https://` connection using the **`serf`** library dumped core due to a bug in the **`serf`** library that SVN uses.
  Work around it on our side, even though the SVN side is being fixed.

So a general upgrade to latest Git (1.8.5 should be out next week) and [latest SVN 1.8](http://samoldak.com/updating-to-svn-1-8-for-mac-os-x-10-8/) can help make things run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

http://bugs.debian.org/534763  suggests it is a bug in libsvn-perl package, try upgrading that

Comment: How does one do that for macports?