# Temp file with moniker 'svn_delta' already in use at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/Git.pm line 1024

Tags: windows, git, perl, svn, cygwin

I am trying to use `git svn clone` with cygwin 64 on a svn repository and I keep getting this message which errors out:

```
Temp file with moniker 'svn_delta' already in use at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/Git.pm line 1024.
```

How do I resolve this issue?  [I found this one that's related to macs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700194/git-svn-clone-fails-on-mac-os-x-temp-file-with-moniker-svn-delta-already-in), but I'm on windows.  The two main answers there say:

1. "Change `~/.subversion/servers`"  I don't know where this is in Windows 7.
2. "a general upgrade to latest Git (1.8.5 should be out next week) and latest SVN 1.8 can help make things run smoothly" But in cygwin I'm stuck with git version 1.7.9.

I have a feeling the latter isn't a necessary step or else everyone using the git svn bridge in cygwin would be complaining like me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18599865/61624) I linked to in my question had the solution.  I had to find the .subversion/servers file which existed in my cygwin path of `~/.subversion/servers`.  I also have a SilkSVN client and I changed that servers file there too.  I found the path for that [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6310641/61624).